# Name of late 80s/early 90s tv show (or possibly TV movie) about two boys with a crush on the same girl. One gets a heart transplant from the other

Tags: story-identification, tv

I vaguely remembered a show (or possibly TV movie) about two (maybe middle school age) friends who have a crush on the same girl. The one friend had a heart condition and needs a transplant, and the other friend is a daredevil type kid. The daredevil kid gets killed doing a stunt (hit by a car I think), and he ends up being a match for the other kids heart and he ends up getting it. After he recovers, he starts trying to get close to the girl they had the crush on, but every time he does his heart starts to give out.

They end up finding out that the daredevil's soul is still in the heart, and his “spirit” is jealous of them being together.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [Heart on a Chain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eerie,_Indiana#Episodes) episode of Eerie, Indiana.

> Marshall and a classmate, Devon (Cory Danziger) fall for the new girl,
>   Melanie Monroe (Danielle Harris) who needs a heart transplant. When
>   Devon dies in a gruesome accident, Melanie receives Devon's heart —
>   and her personality changes almost overnight. Is Melanie acting out
>   because she feels guilty over Devon's death or does Devon's spirit
>   live on in his transplanted heart, which is now in Melanie's body?

Eerie, Indiana was like a junior X-Files. Marshall investigates all the wacky stuff happening around his town.

The major difference between the question and the episode is that the girl gets the heart, not the rival and she then begins to act more like the daredevil, using his stock phrases and actions.

Comment: THATS IT!!!  I’ve been trying to remember the name forever!  Thank you so much. Thank you for cleaning up the chain of events for me too. It was 27 years ago, so I guess I just mis-remembered it.